# How to create custom UI for Airdrop sharing without using UIActivityViewController?

Tags: swift

I want to create **custom UI** for the Airdrop and show active devices to send file through Airdrop in my UI in SWIFT.

Comment: You can't... its a system operation and has no public SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

custom airdrop UI is not feasible , you can do this by UIActivityViewController